# Child div height sticking out of parent wrapper

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make the navigation stay within the boundaries of the wrapper. The navigation is inside a wrapper with 100% height, and I want the navigation to fill the remaining height. Naturally I used 100% on the navigation as well, but then it sticks out of the `div`. What am I doing wrong?

```css
body {
  background: blue;
  background-size: cover;
  font: 14px "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 2% 4%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  height: 100vh;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  height: 75px;
  width: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  background: purple;
}

.box {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
}

.box:last-child {
  sborder-bottom: 2px solid #EBEBEB;
  sswidth: 100%;
}

.box:first-child {
  width: 223px;
  sborder-right: 2px solid #EBEBEB;
}

.main {
  padding: 10px;
  order: 2;
  height: 100%;
}

.side {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  background: #292F32;
  color: #6B757D;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 0 0 223px;
  order: 1;
  height: 100%;
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="box">
        intersect
      </div>

      <div class="box">
        rest
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="side">
      navigation
    </div>

    <div class="main">
      main content
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Add  overflow:hidden; to the .wrapper class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

You use `height: 100%` all over, which won't work properly cross browsers together with Flexbox.

Instead, make use Flexbox own properties, e.g. `flex: 1`, that will fill the remaining space/height in a flex column container.

The simplest solution in this case is to wrap the `side`/`main`, make the inner wrapper `display: flex` and change the outer wrapper to `flex-direction: column`

---

The need of a wrapper is because with a wrap enable flex row container,
it's the `align-content` that controls whether the items *stretch* and fill the parent's height.

As you gave the `header` a height, you won't be able to accomplish that, as it will produce a *gap* between the `header` and `side`/`main`, unless the `header`'s height is fixed and shouldn't expand even if the content force it to.

And if that is the case, where you use fixed heights, no need for Flexbox in the first place, you can instead use [CSS Calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).

---

*Note, I also removed some unnecessary properties, which were either not needed or their default.*

Stack snippet

```css
body {
  background: blue;
  background-size: cover;
  font: 14px "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 2% 4%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;           /*  added  */
  height: 100vh;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  height: 75px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  background: purple;
}

.box {
  padding: 10px;
}

.box:last-child {
  sborder-bottom: 2px solid #EBEBEB;
  sswidth: 100%;
}

.box:first-child {
  width: 223px;
  sborder-right: 2px solid #EBEBEB;
}

.wrapper-inner {
  flex: 1;                          /*  fill available space/height  */
  display: flex;
}


.main {
  padding: 10px;
}

.side {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  background: #292F32;
  color: #6B757D;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 0 0 223px;
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="box">
        intersect
      </div>

      <div class="box">
        rest
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper-inner">
      <div class="side">
        navigation
      </div>

      <div class="main">
        main content
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. Very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add `height:calc(100vh - 75px);` to the `.side` class instead of the `height:100%`

What is that?

height:calc(100vh - 75px)

```
--> 100vh is the 100 (viewpoint units, thx to @LGSon for correcting me) 
--> - 75px is the height of the `.header` class
```

```css
body {
  background: blue;
  background-size: cover;
  font: 14px "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 2% 4%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  height: 100vh;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  height: 75px;
  width: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  background: purple;
}

.box {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
}

.box:last-child {
  sborder-bottom: 2px solid #EBEBEB;
  sswidth: 100%;
}

.box:first-child {
  width: 223px;
  sborder-right: 2px solid #EBEBEB;
}

.main {
  padding: 10px;
  order: 2;
  height: 100%;
}

.side {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  background: #292F32;
  color: #6B757D;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 0 0 223px;
  order: 1;
  height:calc(100vh - 75px); <-----------HERE
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="box">
        intersect
      </div>

      <div class="box">
        rest
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="side">
      navigation
    </div>

    <div class="main">
      main content
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That will eventually make content disappear.

Comment: Edited the snippet, now its exactly the height he needs

Comment: The 100 in `100vh` is not (value of height) of the wrapper, `vh` stands for viewport units.